# spring mvc request mapping conventions

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to come with a good convention to do request mappings in my application

right now i have

```
RegistrationController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/registerMerchant")
   ...
   @RequestMapping(value="/registerUser")
   ...
}
```

but this isnt ideal since by looking at the url you might not know to look in `RegistrationController` for the code.

Is there a way i can programmitically prepend the **controller name** of those mappings making them:

```
/registration/registerMerchant
/registration/registerUser
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not programmatically, but this sort of pattern I've seen working:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/registration/**")
RegistrationController {
   @RequestMapping(value="**/registerMerchant")
   ...
   @RequestMapping(value="**/registerUser")
   ...
}
```

Having said that, in the past I've found this inordinately hard to get working in the way I'd expect. It *can* be made to work, though.

Comment: you found the above pattern hard to use? why? also, i am not married to this convention yet, can you recommend some other sane way to do request mappings?

Comment: @mkoryak: It's easy to understand, but Spring MVC isn't great at letting you diagnose it when you get it even slightly wrong. it's the best pattern I've come across, though.

Comment: I agree that this can be a little painful. The key here is, after using a class-level @RequestMapping, making sure that your method level annotations do not begin with /.

Answer (score 6):

I think **/ at the method level is too much noise. On a different note, the URI could be made more REST like with more nouns and less verbs.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class RegistrationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/merchant/register")
    public void processMerchantRegistration() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/register")
    public void processUserRegistration() {

    }

}
```